# How can i open a custom dialog without activity (or when i received push notitfication by Service) on Android Application

Tags: android

How can i open a custom dialog without activity (or when i received push notitfication by Service) on Android Application

just like line app received push notification and popup a dialog that

can reply the message

Comment: Could you use an AlertDialog with a custom layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission.

Follow this [Blog](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/)

Comment: i followed the blog, but windows doesn't appear
i called addView in GCMIntentService class onMessage Function
and got error msg as follow:
sending message to a handler on a dead thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Using GCMIntentService**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
public static String SENDER_ID = "yor sender id";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 */
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device unregistered
 */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");

    // open dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewScheduleDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
    dialog.setView(viewScheduleDialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Title");

    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // your code
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your reply!
i followed your code, but i got error message as follow:
"android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"

do you have any idea about that ?

thanks a lot!